# How to Split a string and print all the substrings using cut

Tags: linux, bash, text, cut

I have some comma separated strings and want to split them using cut command in bash:

```
This, is a, sample input.
This, is, another string, which could, appear, in my text, file.
```

I also want to print all the substrings in the output. 
The desired output of the first string is:

```
This
is a
sample input.
```

and this is the desired output of the second string:

```
This
is
another string
which could
appear
in my text
file.
```

but since the number of commas(substrings) is not fixed in all of the strings, I don't know how to tell the cut command to show all the substrings. (for example there 2 commas in the first string and 6 in the second). Is there any way to do this in bash (with cut or other commands)?

I have to add that although my examples in this post are in English, My actual strings are in Arabic language. I mean the command which I want to use, have to be able to work with Unicode characters.

Comment: Is bash a requirement? The unicode support in Python 3 *might* make it easier to handle the arabic text.

Comment: no it is not a requirement, but preferred. Since I am writing a bash script for doing some other processes on those strings, I prefer to split them in bash, too. (I mean I have some files, I want to read them, split their lines and do some other processes). By the way, if there isn't another handy tool for this purpose I have to do splitting using Perl...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you wanted cut:

```
line='This, is a, sample input.'
for i in $(seq 1 $(echo "$line," | tr -dc ',' | wc -c)); do
  echo $line | cut -d, -f$i; 
done
```

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it the problem can be approached in two ways.

1. read strings in chunks until you get a comma. Use **`read`** and a **bash array**
2. replace commas (`,`) with newlines (`\n`). Use **`tr`**.

IIRC, `tr` should be unicode safe, while `sed` depends on the implementation. I am not 100% sure about this, I will have to look it up.

---

using a **Bash array**:

```
$ IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "μήλο, πορτοκάλι μπανάνα, αχλάδι"
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]# }"
μήλο
πορτοκάλι μπανάνα
αχλάδι
```

---

using **`tr`**

```
$ echo "μήλο, πορτοκάλι μπανάνα, αχλάδι" | tr ',' '\n'
μήλο
 πορτοκάλι μπανάνα
 αχλάδι
```

notice that this substitution will leave a leading space, because words have a space after comma.

you can get away with that by reprocessing the output to get rid of leading spaces,
or preprocessing the string to supress spaces after commas

---

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
aa="This, is a, sample input."
bb="This, is, another string, which could, appear, in my text, file."

echo $aa|tr ',' '\n'

echo $bb|tr ',' '\n'
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask you to use **awk** for this!!

```
$ echo "μήλο, πορτοκάλι, αχλάδι" | awk '{FS=", "}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
```

this should give

```
μήλο
πορτοκάλι
αχλάδι
```

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter: I tried giving one new line and this doesn't accpet!! How do you do that?? Thanks for editing anyway!! :)

Comment: if you put four or more spaces before your line it will be formatted as code. to simply change a line, leave two spaces at the end of the previous line. This is markdown markup. Search more about it on the web; it is everywhere these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cut** and **awk** too.

This [example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/processing-the-delimited-files-using-cut-and-awk.html) shows how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tr command

```
 IN="This, is a, sample input."

arr=$(echo $IN | tr "," "\n")

for x in $arr
do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are adverse to child processes, use Bash:

```
str='This, is a, sample input.'

IFS=','
set $str
# Remove leading spaces
while (( $# > 0 ))
do   
    echo "${1# }"    
    shift
done
```

EDIT: and here is a Perl solution:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'This, is a, sample input.';
my @subs = split(', ',$str);

local $" = "\n";
print "@subs\n";
```

Comment: Is doing this in perl easier than bash? How would it be?

Comment: A little easier in Perl - depends what you need to do with the substrings once you have them.